# NSStatusBarButton == nil when NSStatusItem was created?

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa, nsstatusitem

I've read the header files: **NSStatusBarButton.h** and **NSStatusItem.h**, which from what I've understanding a `NSStatusBarButton` will be created when a parent `NSStatusItem` item is created.

I can confirm it when I tested it in Playground, but the same code get me error when unwrapping the NSStatusItem.button, which says it's nil.

At first I thought it was because my project was created during the betas so it has a glitch or sort, so I created a new project and port the codes to the new one, still get the same result.

What am I missing here? Or it's just a weird bug?